# Using RegEx in Google Sheets to transform 1 + 1h into 2?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm working on a spreadsheet that handles my company's inventory report. We mark quantities with a number, (1, 2, 7, etc). We mark "holds" in the same cell with an 'h', (i.e. 1+1h, 0+2h, 5+3h)

The problem is that we submit holds + inventory together. Can I use a combination of excel functions and RegEx such that:

```
1 + 1h => 2
0 + 5h => 5
3 => 3
2 + 3h => 5
```

Sidenote - I realize it would be much easier to mark holds in a different cell, but my coworkers/managers won't go for it.

Comment: is "1 + 1h" in one cell?

Comment: Yes, "1 + 1h" in one cell

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(L1:L<>"", QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(L1:L, "h", ), "+"))*1, 
 "select Col1+Col2 label Col1+Col2''", 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Clever. Is there a way to do this for individual cells, rather than entire columns? I need to transform each cell individually.

Comment: sure, you can just use: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(L1, "h", ), "+"))*1))`

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! No RegEx needed I suppose.